# Return max value between some limit and another variable in python

Tags: python

Is there a quicker way to do this in python ?

```
def returnmax(limit,nbr):  
  if nbr>=limit:
    return limit
  else:
    return nbr
```

Comment: `return limit if nbr >= limit else nbr` - a shorter version

Comment: ahh, I see, so there isn't a handy python function that does the same thing ? Alright then, thanks a lot

Comment: if you are looking for the max element then `max(limit, nbr)` would do

Comment: OP is probably looking for min. - `return min(limit, nbr)` - although I wouldn't recommend a separate function just for one line of code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can simply give like this.

```
(nbr, limit) [nbr>=limit]
```

or you can use lambda funtion

```
returnmax = lambda nbr, limit: (nbr, limit) [nbr>=limit]
```

Thank You

Comment: any answer here that fails to mention `min` or `max` functions, but instead offers convoluted solutions (in particular the second) that are basically obfuscation, are so unuseful they verge on disinformation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the max() function
this will compare the difference between the numbers you pass in and return the biggest number:

input:

```
nbr = 2
limit = 10
print(max(limit,nbr))
```

output:

```
10
```